# For a constant mass system, does breaking translation invariance imply breaking time invariance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, noethers-theorem

If a system broke translation invariance and hence momentum isn't conserved, would this not allow an object to increase its velocity relative to an observer that is initially stationary with respect to it, and hence its kinetic energy?

I understand that time and space are linked in general relativity, but does this not imply they are also linked in Newtonian physics (as momentum and energy conservation also arise in Newtonian physics from translation and time invariance)?

Anything that could help me understand what I'm misinterpreting would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Spatial translation invariance** means that if initial conditions $(x,v)$ at $t=t_0$ give rise to a motion $x=x(t)$, then initial conditions $(x+s,v)$ at time $t_0$ give rise to a motion $x=x(t)+s$ for every spatial translation $s$.

**Temporal invariance** means that if initial conditions $(x,v)$ at $t=t_0$ give rise to a motion $x=x(t)$, then inital conditions $x,v$ at time $t_0+\tau$ give rise to a motion $x=x(t-\tau)$ for every temporal translation $\tau$.

There is no general relation between the two types of invariance. As an example, a mass $m>0$ attached to a spring of constant $k>0$ and length $x_0$ satisfies Newton equation $$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -k(x-x_0)\:.$$

If $k$>0 and $m>0$ are constant, this system is not invariant under spatial translations but is invariant under temporal translations in the sense pointed out above.

If we instead assume that $k=k_0t$ for some constant $k_0>0$ and $m>0$ constant, also temporal invariance is broken.

If $k=0$ and $m>0$ is constant,  both notions of invariance are valid.

If eventually we assume $k=0$ and $m=m_0t$ for some constant $m_0>0$, we finally have spatial invariance preserved and temporal invariance broken.
Alternatively, a system with spatial invariance preserved and temporal invariance broken is
$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -k_0t\:,$$
where the mass $m$ is constant.